# Python, how to work with an already opened HTML session in a browser?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, browser, session-cookies

I am trying to make a script that would navigate to an already opened HTML session in my browser and then extract particular data (e.g. title of a blog) to a *.txt file by searching a specified xpath.

The problem is that I didn't find anything that would work. Selenium or requests libs always need to GET to a website, and I don't need that. This will always ask the server, then I'd have to log in again using credentials and so on...

I hope that there is a way to tell Python: "navigate to this opened tab in my browser -> 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' and find me my desired xpath"

I want my script to be light-weight and simple, meaning:

- navigate to the chosen tab in my browser without connecting to a server
- find a text under the specified xpath
- save that text to a *.txt file

No log in to server needed, no credentials. Whatever is stored on my computer, I want to work with that.

Because I'm new to python and scripting altogether, I tried to use selenium, requests, and pywebcopy using their basic functions. I don't want to spend month before I finally find a solution somehow. I tried ChatGPT but it couldn't help me any more than suggesting downloading firefox (my main browser) extentions or using some python libraries that would mimick keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Have you considered writing browser extension for that purpose?

Comment: You want your script to mimic your actions to right click on a page, yet you do not want a library that would mimic a keyboard and mouse ??? This seems contradictory.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - actually, I didn't think about writing an extension. I'm at the starting point of my Python adventure, so I don't know how to do it, actually. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @ScottC - maybe I put it the wrong way. I only wanted to tell you guys where my script should go and what it should do. I hoped that a Python script could handle identifying (navigating to) the tab location and then searching for the proper part using xpath. I wrote that and I thought it was clear. I'll replace bold text with non-bold

Comment: You will almost certainly have to write a browser extension.  Things like "navigating to a browser tab" are easy for *you*, and they are easy for *the browser program*, but they are very hard for "outside" programs.  Each "tab" is represented in the memory allotted to the browser by the OS.  Other programs, generally, don't have access to this memory, and, even if they did, it would look like a bunch of `010001010110...` is that a tab, or a menu, or some html or an image ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.  Browsers expose some of this internal stuff nicely by way of extension APIs.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to get Selenium to open a browser for you, and then wait for you to load the desired page. You can set a timeout of 300 seconds, which would give you 5 minutes to navigate to the desired page. Once the the xpath is detected, you can then do the usual stuff.

Here is an example:

- Load a page and navigate to `https://www.google.com`
- The script will wait for you to navigate to the desired page.
- In my example, I will navigate to `https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html` **manually**.
- The driver then looks for the text input box on that page to load, and once it does it will print the `id` attribute of that text input box.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# This will open chrome browser 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

# Now wait for me to manually load a page, and look for the CSS selector.
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#my-text-id"))
)

# Once the selector is found, it will grab the `id` attribute and print it
text_input = element.get_attribute("id")
print(text_input)
```

#### Output:

```
my-text-id
```

Here is a picture of the [text input box](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html) on the page I manually navigated to:

[image: Web form]

Comment: Hmm, it feels like a partial solution. It may help me avoid some security issues, where the server would normally notice automated script and possibly prevent me even from providing credentials. 
Isn't there really any way to just tell some python library: 'here is an open tab in my browser -> "https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html", please work on that'? Otherwise, I will have to resort to do half the work manually (or use a lib to mimick keyboard&mouse, which would be pretty time consuming and not efficient)

Comment: If you have the tab open in your browser, have you not already done half the work manually ? How did that tab come to be open, how did it navigate to that page, how did it log in ? This solution gives you time to do that stuff manually, and will then allow you to continue from where you left off, which is what you want it to do??

Comment: At this point, I will simply download that page manually and try to work with that as a simple text file. If I fail at that, then I'll try your workaround for sure. Thanks